# Spark job to aggregate cassandra data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I am new to spark. I have the following table in cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE cust_actions (
   orgid text,
   empid int,
   custid int,
   date timestamp,
   action text
   PRIMARY KEY (orgid, empid, custid, date)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (empid ASC, custid ASC, date DESC)
```

This table contains data for each of the actions that an employee takes on a customer. The table gets more than 10 million inserts per day. I have a 3 node cassandra cluster, running on 18 core machines with 32g ram each.

I want to aggregate the data per day, i.e. on a particular day how many actions were taken on a customer. For this purpose, I have created another table:

```
CREATE TABLE daily_cust_actions (
    custid int,
    date date,
    action text,
    count int,
    PRIMARY KEY (custid, date, action)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date ASC, action ASC)
```

In order to do this, I want to use spark (please suggest if this is wrong, or there are some other alternatives as well). I am running spark on one of these cassandra machines (mentioned above), with a master and a slave having 9 executors, each of these executors have 1g ram and 2 cores each.

The table size if approx 70g. I am not able to aggregate this data. This works fine for a smaller data set though. Here is my spark script:

```
object DailyAggregation {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "host1,host2,host3")
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")            
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra")            
    .set("spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb", "10") //have tried multiple options here

val sc = new SparkContext("spark://host", "spark-cassandra", conf)

val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("mykeyspace","cust_actions")

val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")

val df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

val startDate = df.parse("2018-08-13")
val endDate = df.parse("2018-09-14")

sc.parallelize(
  rdd.select("custid", "date", "action")
    .where("date >= ? and date < ?", startDate, endDate)
    .keyBy(row => (
      row.getInt("custid"),
      df.format(row.getLong("date")),
      row.getString("action"))).map { case (key, value) => (key, 1) }
    .reduceByKey(_ + _).collect()
    .map { case (key, value) => (key._1, key._2, key._3, value) })
  .saveToCassandra("mykeyspace", "daily_cust_actions")

sc.stop()
 }
}
```

I have tried different things, increasing/decreasing memory/executors, increasing/decreasing `spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb` value and tuning some spark environment variables. But each time I get a different error. It shows 2 stages, the first stage always runs smoothly, but it always fails in the second stage.

I have seen a lot of different errors. Currently I am getting the following error:

`2018-09-15 16:36:05 INFO  TaskSetManager:54 - Task 158.1 in stage 1.1 (TID 1293) failed, but the task will not be re-executed (either because t
he task failed with a shuffle data fetch failure, so the previous stage needs to be re-run, or because a different copy of the task has already
 succeeded).
2018-09-15 16:36:05 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 131.1 in stage 1.1 (TID 1286, 127.0.0.1, executor 18): FetchFailed(null, shuffleId=0, m
apId=-1, reduceId=131, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0`

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also get the error: 
`org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failure while fetching StreamChunkId{streamId=434199629104, chunkIndex=31}: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`

Comment: and also: WARN  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:66 - No more replicas available for taskresult_2621 !

Comment: It is because you are using the collect operation. The data can't fit into the driver.

Comment: I wouldn't used spark here. You could use a materialized view. For every insert in main table, just populate the materialized view which will look exactly like your `daily_cust_actions` table, just without the count. getting the count would be a simple CQL `SELECT count(*) FROM …`